# Docker Geonode : Origin server was unable or unwilling to find the resource requested

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, gis

I've setup a docker instance of Geonode , and whenever I try to upload a shapefile , I get this Error .

No idea what I've done wrong .
The geoserver works fine on the domain and it handles most of everything fine , it's just has a problem with shapefile projects.

For reference , I'm running the latest release as of 23 of February 2022 for docker images and a server with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What is the error? How are you uploading the shapefile? Check the log with `docker logs my_container_name`

Comment: The tittle is the error ,  here's a snap from the page : https://imgur.com/a/IuvVfym

Comment: check the log container. Add both logs to your question. Check if the app starts without errors. Compare logs of dockerized and no dockerized

Comment: It's six containers , and therefore I'm not sure where the error occurs , I've tracked down the logs for each container but the 2 that do show errors , it's unrelated . I could post the logs from all six containers , but then again , it's six containers it's going to be utter chaos

Comment: six container will be a pain but you don't have a choice. Check the logs. Logs are the cornerstone of problems resolution